# How to "Remove from dictionary" in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

i mistakenly added a misspelled word to dictionary in MS word 2007.(right click > add to dictionary)
I tried a lot but could not find a way to remove that particular entry.
Is there a way to do this so that my spell check works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some information I found elsewhere:

In Word 2007, go to **Office Button | Word Options | Proofing** and click on **Custom Dictionaries…** In the **Custom Dictionaries** dialog, select CUSTOM.DIC and click on **Edit Word List…** This will open a dialog showing a list of words. Find the word you inadvertently added and delete or correct it, then click **OK** to close the dialog.

Hope it works!